# Non-normal subgroups of triangle groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Consider the triangle group $\Delta(a, b, c)$ for some $a, b, c > 1$, given by three generators $x$, $y$, and $z$, such that $x^2 = y^2 = z^2 = (xy)^a = (yz)^b = (zx)^c = 1$.

Can anyone provide an example of a non-normal subgroup of some $\Delta(a, b, c)$ of finite index, containing only products of even numbers of generators (i.e., a subgroup of the corresponding von Dyck group), and containing no conjugate of any nontrivial power of $xy$, $yz$, or $zx$?

Furthermore, I would particularly be interested in examples where $a = 2$.

Comment: At least you know that there are such subgroups (unless $(a,b,c)=(2,2,2)$ as $\Delta$ is then abelian). Indeed otherwise we can assume $c>2$ and then you can choose the subgroup $\{1,z\}$ if $\Delta$ is finite. If $\Delta$ is infinite, there is a normal subgroup of finite index $N$ such that in $\Delta/N$, the orders of $xy,yz,zx$ are $a,b,c$ respectively (it exists because $\Delta$ is residually finite). Then choose any non-normal subgroup of $N$, since you want a non-normal subgroup.

Comment: Ah, $\{1, z\}$ doesn't work; I want subgroups which contain only products of even numbers of generators, while $z$ is a product of an odd number of generators.

(As for the latter case, I have to think about the residually finite reasoning some more.)

Comment: Oh yes I forgot. In the infinite case it's no problem, just intersect with the von Dyck group first if necessary.

Comment: Then in the finite case it seems not to exist at all: if $a=b=2$, you have a dihedral group (times one of order 2). Then in the dihedral group, all subgroup of the von Dyck group will be normal. So the only remaining cases are the Coxeter groups of type $A_3,B_3, H_3$. In $A_3$ and $H_3$, the von Dyck subgroup has index 2, and index 4 in $B_3$. In $A_3=Sym_4$, it does not exist either, and also in the binary icosahedral (of order 120) $H_3$. I haven't checked $B_3$ (of order 48).

Comment: In the infinite case, pardon my inability to see it right away, but why is it clear the triangle group is residually finite? And, supposing we take N as above (intersected with the von Dyck group if necessary), how do we know it has a non-normal subgroup?

Comment: This is a finitely generated Coxeter group, so it's linear over a field (see e.g. Bourbaki on Lie groups and Lie algebras) and hence residually finite. But I guess here one can use a more direct argument (since you need much less than just being residually finite).

Comment: However my claim there's a non-normal subgroup was a bit quick. It's true as soon as the finite index subgroup (intersected with von Dyck) is non-abelian. This holds unless we have a Coxeter group of affine type. Here the only exceptions are $AA_2$, $CC_2$, $GG_2$, and $II_1$ (here double letter means tilde). They correspond to $(a,b,c)=$ $(3,3,3)$, $(2,4,4)$, $(2,3,6)$, $(2,2,\infty)$. But actually it's OK in the first 3 cases because we get a normal subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}^2$ with a noncentral action. However we get no normal subgroup in the $(2,2,\infty)$ case.

Comment: Ah, ok, I see now the residual finiteness, but why does N being non-abelian guarantee a non-normal subgroup? What prevents N from being a Hamiltonian group? [Or, rather, I guess, what's really of interest isn't necessarily subgroups of N which are non-normal in N, but rather subgroups of N which are non-normal in the ambient triangle group; still, why does non-abelianness guarantee such a subgroup of N?]

Comment: Because hamiltonian groups have an abelian subgroup of index 2, by the structure theorem. Yet here you need a non-normal subgroup of finite index. So it's enough to have a finite quotient that is not hamiltonian. Actually if a f.g. residually finite group has the property that all its finite quotients have an abelian subgroup of index 2, then it itself has an abelian subgroup of index 2.

Comment: Ah, ok, great; thanks for all your help! If you post your comments as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: OK, I'll do this when I find time. Btw, the question actually sounded like you know the answer and you ask for a more explicit example.

Comment: Explicit examples would be good as well. If I at any point sound like I know anything, that is misleading. :)